# Problem with font commands as `l3keys2e` values

Tags: fonts, expl3, l3keys

I'm setting some fonts and font-related commands using `l3keys`, and that works just fine—but it seems there's an issue when setting the same keys via `l3keys2e`. Is this expected behavior? Is there a way around it?

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{keydebug.sty}

\RequirePackage{expl3}

\ProvidesExplPackage
    {keydebug} {2019/00/00}
    {0.0}      {}

\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\keys_define:nn { keydebug } {
    myfont      .tl_set:N       = \myfont,
    myfont      .initial:n      = \it,               % 1
}

\ProcessKeysOptions { keydebug }

% \keys_set:nn { keydebug } { myfont = \it }         % 4

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{keydebug}                                % 1
% \usepackage[myfont=\relax]{keydebug}               % 2
% \usepackage[myfont=\it]{keydebug}                  % 3-4

\begin{document}
{\myfont Hello, world!}
\end{document}
```

The numbers to the right indicates four scenarios, and which of the given lines should be uncommented/active in each.

## Scenario 1

Initializing via the `.initial` property works just fine, and results in the following:

[image: using .initial]

## Scenario 2

Here I supply a command via the package options—in this case `\relax`, but other commands seem generally to work just fine. In this case, the result is the following, as expected:

[image: with \relax]

## Scenario 3

Now comes the problem. If I try to supply a font command such as `\it` or `\bfseries` or the like, I get the following error:

```
./keydebug.tex:27: Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
                \inaccessible
l.27
```

## Scenario 4

It's not *supplying* the command that's the problem—it's using it later. If I ensure that I overwrite it (still in the preamble, here), things are just fine:

[image: overwriting]

So … any suggestions for fixes or workarounds?

Comment: Off topic: please don't use `\it`, rather use `\textit`.

Comment: In a per-document basis you can load the `kvoptions-patch` package before loading your `keydebug` package, which changes LaTeX's package option handling and inhibits the `\edef` Joseph mentioned. (It seems that in total there are two `\edef`s in the process, so `\usepackage[myfont=\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\itshape]{keydebug}` should work as well).

Comment: @JosephWright I think you meant `\itshape` :-)

Comment: I know :-) This is partly for insertion in places where I can't wrap the argument in braces, which I'm using `\itseries` and `\bfseries` etc., there. But where I can, I use `\textit` (for automatic italics correction), etc. But `\textit` doesn't fare much better, here.

Comment: Right, though `\itshape` doesn't fare any better either :-)

Comment: (And, yes, I too meant `\itshape`, of course—not `\itseries` :-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is out of the control of `l3keys2e`. The LaTeX2e kernel processes options before they are passed to packages, and the code which does that (written in the early 1990s) carries out `\edef` expansion. It was written on the basis that options would be simple lists of words, not keyvals and certainly not commands. The LaTeX team are exploring approaches to 'fixing' this, but there are non-trivial issues. At present, you should stick to using a 'setup' approach for any keys that do not strictly expect strings.

Comment: Right. Yeah, I have a separate setup command too, of course, so I guess I'll just mention this in the docs, then :-)

Comment: Ended up (for now) placing `\ProcessKeysOptions` between two blocks of `\keys_define:nn`, with the first defining those keys that may be set in `\usepackage`.